# Strange const_iterator behavior

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, const-iterator

I'm doing a main.cpp to test my implementation of a sparse matrix, where I create two const_iterators:

```
SparseMatrix<double>::const_iterator a,b;
a=mata.begin(); //mata previously created as SparseMatrix<double>
b=mata.end();
... //code goes on
```

The problem is that it doesn't call begin and end (it doesn't even do the initial cout), but if I create two iterators it works.
Here's how I implemented begin and end for const_iterators.

```
const_iterator begin() const
{
    cout<<"Begin"<<endl;
    int minr=minRow();
    int minc=minCol(findRow(minr));
    mcol * mc=findCol(findRow(minr),minc);
    const_iterator x;
    if(mc!=NULL)
    {
        T* dato=&(mc->data);
        x= const_iterator(genElement(minr,minc,dato));
    }
    else
    {
        x=const_iterator(NULL);
    }
    x.setSM(const_cast<SparseMatrix<T>*>(this));
    return x;
}

const_iterator end() const
{
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    const_iterator x= const_iterator(NULL);
    x.setSM(const_cast<SparseMatrix<T>*>(this));
    return x;
}
```

A strange thing I noticed is that if I create two const_iterators inside a SparseMatrix's class method, they work.

Comment: How do you know they aren't created? Most likely the compiler optimized them away because they weren't being used.

Comment: I know because the code goes on and gives me errors, it says that const_iterator operator++() is trying to read an unallocated memory area, because it hasn't ever been assigned anything with begin() and end()

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you posted: Can you show us a minimal, fully-compilable program that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I've reverted your edit because it changed the question to such an extent that all the existing comments and answer became nonsensical.

Comment: ok, then I'll open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, "`mata` [*sic*] previously created as `SparseMatrix<double>`", but your `begin` and `end` that you show are marked `const`. For those `const` member functions to be called, the object `meta` must be `const`, else the non-`const` versions of `begin` and `end` will be called.

Comment: How should I do if I want it to be called on a non-const object?
I need a const iterator with read-only permissions, and a normal iterator with also write permissions.

Comment: @Vektor88 usually people have the non-`const` member function return a `iterator` and the `const` version return a `const_iterator`. Also you can have a non-`const` function `cbegin` that returns a `const_iterator` if you want as well.